# Running out of memory with UIImage creation on an offscreen Bitmap Context by NSOperation

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimage, nsoperation

I have an app with multiple UIView subclasses that acts as pages for a UIScrollView. UIViews are moved back and forth to provide a seamless experience to the user. Since the content of the views is rather slow to draw, it's rendered on a single shared CGBitmapContext guarded by locks by NSOperation subclasses - executed one at once in an NSOperationQueue - wrapped up in an UIImage and then used by the main thread to update the content of the views.

```
-(void)main {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

if([self isCancelled]) {
    return;
}
if(nil == data) {
    return; 
}

// Buffer is the shared instance of a CG Bitmap Context wrapper class
// data is a dictionary
CGImageRef img = [buffer imageCreateWithData:data];
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:img];
CGImageRelease(img);

if([self isCancelled]) {
    [image release];
    return;
}

NSDictionary * result = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:image,@"image",id,@"id",nil];

// target is the instance of the UIView subclass that will use
// the image
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateContentWithData:) withObject:result waitUntilDone:NO];

[result release];
[image release];

[pool release];
}
```

The updateContentWithData: of the UIView subclass performed on the main thread is just as simple

```
-(void)updateContentWithData:(NSDictionary *)someData {

NSDictionary * data = [someData retain];

if([[data valueForKey:@"id"]isEqualToString:[self pendingRequestId]]) {

    UIImage * image = [data valueForKey:@"image"];
    [self setCurrentImage:image];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

// If the image has not been retained, it should be released together
// with the dictionary retaining it
[data release];
}
```

The drawLayer:inContext: method of the subclass will just get the CGImage from the UIImage and use it to update the backing layer or part of it. No retain or release is involved in the process.

The problem is that after a while I run out of memory. The number of the UIViews is static. CGImageRef and UIImage are created, retained and released correctly (or so it seems to me). Instruments does not show any leaks, just the free memory available dip constantly, rise a few times, and then dip even lower until the application is terminated. The app cycles through about 2-300 of the aforementioned pages before that, but I would expect to have the memory usage reach a more or less stable level of used memory after a bunch of pages have been already skimmed at fast speed or, since the images are up to 3MB in size, deplete way earlier.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old posting, but in case it helps anybody else ....  This looks like a case of memory fragmentation.  We have an app that behaves the same way.  The amount of memory actually allocated by the app never reaches dangerous levels, but if you look at the amount of resident memory for the app (using VM Tracker snapshots in the Allocations Instrument, or the Activity Monitor Instrument), it climbs inexorably over time until a not-very-large transient spike kills the app.

The app in question is a multi-threaded app that makes tons of transient allocations in a large range of sizes, the timing of which can't be predicted or controlled.  Such an app has to be paranoid about releasing unneeded memory allocations, not because they take up too much memory per se, but because they can create holes that prevent larger images from fitting into the allocated blocks.  Even smaller allocations that tend to be overlooked are important in fragmentation (granted that the low-level allocator does group allocations by size, which is helpful to an extent).  Memory zones are theoretically helpful for addressing fragmentation but pretty hard to make effective, at least in my experience.  Also, use custom auto-release pools, or better yet, alloc/init as much as you can, and release as early as possible.  The fact that the underlying frameworks are always making their own allocations for caching purposes probably doesn't help.